# How to push score into an array, then display it

Tags: javascript, html, dice

I'm trying to make a dice game where the goal for each of participants is to collect points as fast as possible to pass 100. Each participant can throw the die as many times as they want and add the points, but achieved points within a certain game fall away if a one is rolled. For example, if you have 15 points in a game and have stopped in time, these points can be taken further to round two. These points cannot be lost in a later round and thus become included in the summary.

I've managed to:

- write the code that shows images of dice and sums up the current score (images = 1.png, 2.png etc).
- Resets the current score to 0 when the player rolls a one.

What I need help with is how to write the code that activates the button "done for now" and takes that value and pushes it into an array(????) then clears the score for the next round -> then displaying the score on the site while the other rounds keep on going. It should also sum up the score and throws from each round (first to 100).

Here is my code:

```js
var points = 0;

var start, dice, print;

window.onload = run;

function $(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function run() {
  start = $("throwDice");
  dice = $("dice");
  print = $("print");
  start.onclick = throwDice;
}

function throwDice() {
  var throwD = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  throwD.innerHTML = '<img width="20%" src="' + throwD + '.jpg">';

  add(throwD);
}

function add(value) {

  points += value;

  if (value == 1) {
    points = 0;
    $("print2").innerHTML = "GAME OVER"
  } else {
    $("print2").innerHTML = "";
    $("print").innerHTML = points;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="round">
  <h1>The endless road</h1>
  <button id="throwDice">Throw Dice</button> <button>Done for now</button>
  <div id="dice" class="dice"></div>
  <h2 id="print"></h2>
  <p id="print2"></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please revise your post to explain exactly what your script is or isn't doing. It's rather vague as it is.

Comment: FYI, one _die_, two _dice_.

Comment: Im looking for a solution that when the button "Done for now" is being clicked, the program takes the score gained - variable points - And saves this to an empty array. I need this array to list up on the left or right side of the website while another round goes on. 

When this button is clicked the dice-score that comes up when clicking "thow dice" should reset, but the score you gained will be stored inside the array.

Comment: I understand it being hard when you cant see the dices that is artwork-images on my computer.

Comment: Please *[revise](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56671098/edit)* to explain....

Answer (score 1):

Basically you just have to add another click event listener to the 'Done for now' button whose callback function

- pushes the current points to an array
- resets the points to 0
- updates the text elements on screen

Something like:

```js
var points = 0;
var pointsArray = new Array();
var start, dice, print;


function $(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}

function run() {
  start = $("throwDice");
  dice = $("dice");
  print = $("print");
  start.onclick = throwDice;
  done = $("done");
  done.onclick = stopRound;
}

function stopRound() {
  pointsArray.push(points);
  points = 0;
  $("print").innerHTML = points;
  $("print3").innerHTML = pointsArray;
}

function throwDice() {
  var throwD = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;
  throwD.innerHTML = '<img width="20%" src="' + throwD + '.jpg">';

  add(throwD);
}

function add(value) {

  points += value;

  if (value == 1) {
    points = 0;
    $("print2").innerHTML = "GAME OVER"
  } else {
    $("print2").innerHTML = "";
    $("print").innerHTML = points;
  }
}
run();
```

```html
<div class="round">
  <h1>The endless road</h1>
  <button id="throwDice">Throw Dice</button> <button id="done">Done for now</button>
  <div id="dice" class="dice"></div>
  <p id="print3" style="float:right;"></p>
  <h2 id="print"></h2>
  <p id="print2"></p>

</div>
```